# Android create custom NumberPicker widget

Tags: android

I'm using some `simvot` number picker in application, I want to create custom widget for that and use in all of project, now i'm create this files but I can not set any value for custom widget.

My attributes:

```
<declare-styleable name="CNumberPicker">
    <attr name="maxValue"               format="string" />
    <attr name="minValue"               format="string" />
    <attr name="value"                  format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

My Custom NumberPicker widget:

```
public class CNumberPicker extends net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker implements OnClickListener {

    private int maxValue;
    private int minValue;
    private int value;

    public CNumberPicker(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        processAttributeSet(attrs);
    }

    public CNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CNumberPicker, defStyle, 0);
        processAttributeSet(attrs);

        maxValue = Integer.parseInt(a.getString(R.styleable.CNumberPicker_maxValue));
        minValue = Integer.parseInt(a.getString(R.styleable.CNumberPicker_minValue));

        a.recycle();
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }


    private void processAttributeSet(AttributeSet attrs) {
        this.setMaxValue(attrs.getAttributeIntValue(null, "maxValue", 0));
    }

}
```

My defined widget into xml:

```
<com.sample.widget.CNumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/np_choose_hour"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.20"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:maxValue="10"
    app:minValue="1"
    app:value="5">
</com.sample.widget.CNumberPicker>
```

how to set value defined into xml in layout?

Answer (score 0):

You have to inflate the layout in code.

```
public CNumberPicker(Context context) {
    super(context);
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cnumberpicker, this);
}
```

presuming the layout file is cnumberpicker.xml

EDIT: These 3 functions are constructors. Any one of them could be called to construct the object. By using `this` instead of `super` we can force all constructors to end up calling the 3 parameter constructor. You need some cohesion here. You don't want to copy paste code every time you make one change.

```
public CNumberPicker(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CNumberPicker, defStyle, 0);
    processAttributeSet(attrs);

    // this method allows a default value if no attributes are given. You should use them.
    maxValue = Integer.parseInt(a.getString(R.styleable.CNumberPicker_maxValue,"10"));
    minValue = Integer.parseInt(a.getString(R.styleable.CNumberPicker_minValue,"0"));
    a.recycle();
}
```

Comment: i get an error for `getLayoutInflater()` and how to define layout for  `np_choose_hour`? i have some numberPicker such as Year,month,Day and ... `np_choose_hour` must be programical change

Comment: edited. It has to be the name of the xml file in the layout folder.

Comment: thanks. i get this error now: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'null' as integer` my widget could not get data from attribute and `maxValue` is null and i can not set it